# How to select entities via another entity type using Doctrine's QueryQuilder?

Tags: select, doctrine-orm, query-builder, querying

I want to select entities, that are not provided to the `QueryBuilder#select(...)`. In raw SQL it would look like this:

```
SELECT x.*
FROM aaa a
INNER JOIN bbb b ON a.document_id = b.id
INNER JOIN ccc c ON b.client_user_id = c.id
INNER JOIN xxx x ON c.client_id = x.id
WHERE a.id = 123
```

Now I tried to implement this logic with the `QueryBuilder`:

```
$query = $queryBuilder->select('x')
    ->from(Aaa::class, 'a')
    ->join('a.bbb', 'b')
    ->join('b.ccc', 'c')
    ->join('c.xxx', 'x')
    ->where('a.id = :aId')
    ->setParameter('aId', $aId)
    ->getQuery()
;
```

But it doesn't work:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col -1 near 'SELECT x FROM': Error: Cannot select entity through identification variables without choosing at least one root entity alias.

How to get this working with with Doctrine's QueryQuilder?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's not possible with Doctrine (see the statement of [Benjamin Eberlei](https://github.com/beberlei) to this issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/1672#issuecomment-162355210)).

The **solution** / **workaround** is to define the whole associations chain in the direction from `Xxx` to `Aaa` and then find the `Xxx` entity following the "path" starting `FROM` `Xxx`:

```
$query = $queryBuilder->select('x')
    ->from(Xxx::class, 'x')
    ->join('x.ccc', 'c')
    ->join('c.bbb', 'b')
    ->join('b.aaa', 'a')
    ->where('a.id = :aId')
    ->setParameter('aId', $aId)
    ->getQuery()
;
```